# Yoast SEO and custom fields

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if it was possible to use the advanced custom fields - wysiwyg editor as the default editor for the main content and let yoast read that instead of the default?

Or if that isn't possible then if it is somehow possible to dublicate the content from acf to the main editor.

Or if there is any other way please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit slow in coming, but we had the same exact question and decided to build a plugin to do this:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/ns-seo-custom-fields/

We just released it and found others looking for a solution like this question and hope that it's helpful to the great WP community.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions you can work with.
If you search for Yoast and ACF on the plugin directory you can find the one you like best: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=yoast+ACF

We have a plugin of our own: https://wordpress.org/plugins/yoast-seo-acf-analysis/

Which is open source, so if you find any problems or think of enhancements you can create an issue at the github project: https://github.com/Yoast/yoast-acf-analysis

Hope this helps you.

Jip from Yoast